# display rows vertically using python

Tags: python, csv

I have a large csv file. when i try to access all the rows of the csv file, i get the values horizontally, but i need them vertically, without the quotations.

the code i have used is

```
import csv  
f= open('kopie1.csv', "rt")  
csv_f = csv.reader(f, delimiter=';')  
for row in csv_f:
    print (row)
```

the output i get is

```
['801', '1124', '1178', '1124', '801', '320', '283', '192', '92', '90', '106', '108'.........]
```

but the output i want to get is as

```
801
1124  
1178  
1124  
801  
320
```

Comment: `print("\n".join(row))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of:

```
for row in csv_f:
      print (row)
```

Write:

```
for row in csv_f:
    print('\n'.join(row))
```

Answer (score 0):

This can do the trick:

```
import csv  
f= open('kopie1.csv', "rt")  
csv_f = csv.reader(f, delimiter=';')  
for row in csv_f:
    print (row, '\n')
```